# Change which font package Plots.jl is using for latex strings?

Tags: julia, latex, plots.jl

I am trying to make a plot with the math symbol:

[image: \m]

in the ylabel, which appears in latex as "\mathcal{I}", but this specific symbol cannot be made in Plots.jl. When entering "\mathcal{I}", you instead get:

[image: \m]

Here is a MWE:

```
using Plots
using LaTeXStrings

plot([1],[1],ylabel=L"\mathcal{I}")
```

Which produces:

[image]

The wrong symbol on the y-axis. I have gathered that this is because Plots.jl is using a different font package. Is there any way to change which font package it uses?

I have many many plots, entire libraries really, written using Julia Plots. The convention in my field is to use "\mathcal{I}" and so it would be a great pain for me to change everything in my paper to use "\mathcal{J}" just because this one library cannot print the right symbol.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Thanks to advice from @BallpointBen, I have tried the following code:

```
default(;fontfamily="Bookman"); plot([1],[1],ylabel=L"\mathcal{I}")
```

Unfortunately, for me this produces the error:

[image]

I should point out that it works fine if one renders empty latex or not latex at all. For example, the following code works:

```
default(;fontfamily="Bookman"); plot([1],[1],xlabel="",ylabel=L"")
```

It is only when at least one character in the latex string is asked for (e.g. L"1") that there is a problem. I further realised that the following actually works to get the right symbol:

```
default(;fontfamily="Times Roman");plot([1],[1],ylabel="")
```

Which produces:

[image]

Quite a few font families work by just inserting this literal character, but alas, if one tries to include latex as well, one gets the same error. That is, I try

```
default(;fontfamily="Times Roman"); plot([1],[1],ylabel=string("",L"1"))
```

And obtain:

[image]

One final idea that does not work is trying to make the  character normal text within the latex string as follows:

```
default(;fontfamily="Times Roman"); plot([1],[1],ylabel=L"\textrm{}")
```

Which produces the same output as the first picture that I sent showing the error.

I am looking into solving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the GR backend, you can find the list of available fonts [here](https://gr-framework.org/fonts.html). You can set the default font of Plots.jl using [`default`](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/api/#Plots.default). You have a lot of fonts to choose from, but one that (sort of) works is Bookman.

```
julia> default(; fontfamily="Bookman"); plot([1],[1],ylabel=L"\mathcal{I}")
```

Or you can set the font directly:

```
julia> plot([1],[1], ylabel=L"\mathcal{I}", yguidefont=font("Bookman"))
```

Result:

[image]

Unfortunately this results the LateX being pixelated — not sure why.

Also unfortunate is that the Unicode character `U+2110` Script Capital I, which might've been a suitable substitute, is rendered as something like ℐ in basically every font.

---

Of course, you do not need to use the GR backend. The PGFPlotsX backend uses LaTeX natively (how? not sure, I think it writes tikx and renders it). You will need to `]add PGFPlotsX`.

```
julia> pgfplotsx()
Plots.PGFPlotsXBackend()

julia> plot([1],[1],ylabel=L"\mathcal{I}")

julia> savefig("fig.pdf")
```

This produces a (high-res) PDF, which I've converted to an image below:

[image]

Comment: I have edited my post to include my attempts using the information you have provided

Comment: @DerickDiana see my edit

Comment: Thank you! I am going to accept this as the answer as I'm sure it will be for most people. For me unfortunately, even though changing backends is supposedly not supposed to break your code, since you interact with backends through an interface, I do have code that draw insets and then like, a projection plane which shows where the inset came from in the outer plot. Suddenly, things do not line up when I use pgfplotsx when they worked perfectly before. I have many many plots so I cannot fix this in time. I have decided to accept what I have. But thank you so much for your help!

Comment: That's a bummer. For future reference, I think Makie.jl is a much more reliable plotting package these days.